# How can TEENSY Microcontrollers read ASCI Variables from X-PLANE 11

Tags: teensy

TEENSY Boards have in the USB-MODE "**FLIGHTSIM**" direct access to the variables = **DATAREFS**
of X-PLANE 11.
You can use FLIGHTSIMINTEGER and FLIGHTSIMFLOAT but not a varible for CHARs like the ID of a waypoint
for example "IBZ" or "EDDF" .
I need to read the CHARs to use them in the Display of my FlightSimPanel.
ANY IDEA ?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking about ... please edit your post and explain what you are asking ... pretend that we cannot read your mind

Comment: Please show the code that you're having problems with. Reading data from flight simulators is not something everyone is familiar with.